# Is there a well-defined exponential of an integral operator?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory, exponential-function

I’ve seen $e^{\frac{d}{dx}}$ yield the shift operator, but would $e^{I}$ where $If(x)\equiv \int f(x)dx$ yield something interesting as well (or even something at all)? I’d imagine that it’s defined as the integral operator is better behaved than the differentiation operator, but I it interesting and does this operator have a name?

$e^I$ is just shorthand for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{I^n}{n!}$ as is oftentimes done in operator theory and related fields.

Comment: Whether the formal power series yields a well-defined operator will depend on the function space you're working with; a sufficient pair of conditions for the series to be well-defined is for your space to be a Banach space on which $I$ is bounded. These properties guarantee that the partial sums of the series are a Cauchy sequence in a complete space. One concrete example of such a space are continuous functions on a compact interval under the supremum norm. I don't know whether $e^I$ is *interesting* so I'll leave that for someone else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$e^I$ has a nice expression in terms of an integral kernel, but I don't know of any uses for it.

Rather than work with quotient vector spaces, let $$(If)(x)=\int_0^x{f(t)\,dt}$$  Then, for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, $$(I^nf)(x)=\int_0^x{\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f(t)\,dt}$$ a result [due to Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration) and easy to prove by induction.

Applying Cauchy's formula and noting that power series converge uniformly, \begin{align*}
(e^If)(x)&=f(x)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^x{\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f(t)\,dt}} \\
&=f(x)+\int_0^x{f(t)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!n!}}\,dt} \\
&=f(x)+\int_0^x{\frac{I_1(2\sqrt{x-t})}{\sqrt{x-t}}f(t)\,dt}
\end{align*} where $I_1$ solves the ODE \begin{gather*}
x^2I_1''(x)+xI_1'(x)-(1+x^2)I_1(x)=0 \\
I_1(0)=0
\end{gather*}

Comment: Do you know any interpretation of the final ODE?

Comment: @Bob: It's just the [modified Bessel ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions).  They're special functions that show up whenever you have a power series with a double-factorial in the denominator (like here); IIRC they have physical interpretation as the hyperbolic harmonics: the radial factor in solutions to Laplace's equation with hyperbolic symmetry.