# Utility of the operator $T^s=e^{s\frac{d}{dx}B(x)}$

Tags: operator-theory, transformation

I came across this question: [Is there a well-defined exponential of an integral operator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482654/is-there-a-well-defined-exponential-of-an-integral-operator).

It just got me wondering about some elementary basics of operator theory. I think I understand basically what an operator is. I've worked with some important operators, such as integral transforms, the derivative and the integral.

My question is about the utility of the operator: $$ T^s=e^{s\frac{d}{dx}B(x)} $$

Is my understanding correct that this is (a) an operator and (b) the operator's input is $B(x)$ and the operator takes that input and spits out another function?

How is $T^s$ different than the shift operator? In what operator theory context does $T^s$ show up? Or does it not show up?

I computed an example. For $B(x):=x$ then $T^s=e^s.$ So monomials transform to exponentials under this operator.

Thank you for bettering my understanding here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T^{s}\circ B=e^{s{d B(x)\over dx}}$ is indeed a (non linear) operator. The shift operator is different: $S^{s}\circ B=e^{d\over dx} B(x)$, that is, $S^{s}\circ B=(1+s{d\over dx}+{s^2\over 2}{d\over dx}^2\cdots) B(x)$ which is the Taylor expansion of $B(x+s)$. They don't look obviously connected.